# no puedo guardar datos en mi base de datos mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

[image: guardo lo que ingrese el usuario en $id,$profesor y lo paso pormyqli_query]
[image: clase inicio , es para conectar con la base de dato]

[image: se muestra la estructura de base de dato]

la cosa es que nunca me guarda la información creo que la estructura esta bien tal vez sea un problema de apache o de puertos?

Comment: la base de dato se llama bd_curso

Comment: y estoy en la tabla cursos

Comment: No pongas imagenes de tu codigo, mejor pegalo directamente para que sea mas facil de leer y de replicar, te recomiendo que leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: amigo cambie las comillas '' en $id y$profesor y me funcionó increible pero cierto

Comment: Duh... pues si. Las comillas sencillas no interpretan las variables que están dentro

Answer (score 0):

Uff, tengo bastantes cosas para decirte:

1. NO insertes los datos así. Es peligroso, cualquiera podría tranquilamente hacer SQL injection y borrarte todas las tablas, si quisiera. Te recomiendo que leas un poco de PDO, de prepareStatement y de bindParam. O al menos, que uses mysql_real_escape_string antes de insertar.
2. Las comillas simples imprimen el signo "$", no lo resuelven. Si querés que "resuelvan" el contenido de la variable, usá comillas dobles.
3. Te conviene que el id sea autonumérico, o generado por vos. Vas a prevenir muchos problemas. Por ejemplo: si a mi como usuario me das el control de elegir el id, tranquilamente yo podría editar o cambiar un profesor que ya existe, agregando un id existente. También te podría poner ids inválidos, etc...
4. Después de $resultado, no se ve ninguna flechita. Quizás es un problema de la imagen que pegaste, pero debería ser:

`$resultado->mysqli_query` ...

Saludos!

Comment: Está usando funcional, no objetos